# The application "xyz" was suspended. If you believe this is an error please contact support

Tags: heroku

After restarting the app, it got suspended and I don't know why:

> The application "app" was suspended. If you believe this is an error please contact support.

My Dockerfile looks like

```
CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "vision" ]
```

heroku.yml

```
build:
  docker:
    worker: Dockerfile
```

After restarting or changing any env, the app got suspended. Can you help me understand why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think this should be better redirected to Heroku support (as the error message says) and because of [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746).

Comment: If you still want to post it here, I think you need to provide some more details, such as what _does_ your app do? Or have you at least checked your app logs for any other info? See also this related post: [Heroku free apps Going down, terminating child processes and The application "???" was suspended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59371608/2745495).

Comment: My App connects to telegram amd automates many tasks of users